# Can the Paypal iOS SDK be used to build an iPad POS?

Tags: ios, sdk, paypal

I'm trying to build a quick app for a charity event. Is there a way to delete a scanned credit card as soon as payment completes so that I can use the app to take hundreds of payments in quick succession with the iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the payment completion screen, there's a "Forget this card" link.

However, for the use case you describe, [PayPal Here would be a better fit](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/1).